# how to save and update a record in the same form using mvc viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Surname{get;set;}

    [Required (ErrorMessage="FirstName Required")]
    public string Firstname{get;set;}

    [Required(ErrorMessage="please enter your OtherNames")]
    public string Othername{get;set;}

    [Required(ErrorMessage="please enter your sex")]
     public string Sex{get;set;}

    [Required (ErrorMessage="please enter your DateOfBirth")]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth{get;set;}

   [Required(ErrorMessage="Address is required")]
  public string Address{get;set;}

   [Required(ErrorMessage="city is required")]
    public string City{get;set;}

    [Required(ErrorMessage="State is required")]
    public string State{get;set;}

    public string Country{get;set;}


}
```

i have created an interface which acts as the middleman between my Domain Layer and my WEBUI

```
 public interface IStudentRepository
    {

       IQueryable<Student> Student { get;  }
       //we using a method to save the record into our database
       void Save(Student student);


    }
```

the interface is being implented by my repository class which perfoms all the actions of saving the records into the database and retrieving it..

```
public class EFRepository:IStudentRepository
    {
       private EFDBContext context = new EFDBContext();

       public IQueryable<Student> Student{ get { return context.Students; } }


       public void Save(Student student)
       {

           if (student.ID == 0)
           {

               context.Students.Add(student);
           }

           context.SaveChanges();

       }
```

and then i have a view which creates an instance of the student class and uses the interface to store the records in the database, which works perfectly..

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Registration(Student student)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                studentrepository.Save(student);
            }
            return View(student);
        }
```

this works perfectly for me..

But i want to be able to update this same fields incase the student make changes to the fields and it should overwrite the existing record in the database.
i have seen my tutorials where the student id number is passed as an action link before it overwrites the existing record.

however,what i want is the ability for the student to edit the same form using the same button and the same view being display.any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You just need to check if the student ID exists in the database. If it does, then do an update and if it doesnt, do a create.

Comment: I'm sorry, how is "update" not "saving"?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change you repository method to look something like this:

```
public class EFRepository:IStudentRepository
{
    private EFDBContext context = new EFDBContext();

    public IQueryable<Student> Student{ get { return context.Students; } }


    public void Save(Student student)
    {

       if (student.ID == 0)
       {

            context.Students.Add(student);
       }
       else
       {
           Student existingStudent = context.Students.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == student.ID);

           if(existingStudent != null)
           {
               context.Entry(existingStudent).CurrentValues.SetValues(student);
               context.Entry(existingStudent).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;

           }

        }

        context.SaveChanges();
}
```

or you can use the Entity Framework Attach method as this will automatically track the object state and update the details

Comment: Why haven't this been upvoted yet ? It's the perfect solution, clean, simple. Pure ASP.NET way to go.